# IndexError: list index out of range While Trying to Scrape Specific Columns on a Table?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So first off, here's the code I am running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Scraping information from https://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html"""

import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html"
county = {}


def counties(countyArg):
    """Fills the `county` variable"""
    f = open("counties.txt")
    for line in f.readlines():
        countyArg[line] = 0

def scrape(urlArg, countyArg):
    """Scrape Site Based on HTML"""
    black = 0
    white = 0
    hispanic = 0

    page = requests.get(urlArg)
    html = page.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        if row.findAll('td')[8] == 'Black':
            black += 1
        elif row.findAll('td')[8] == 'White':
            white += 1
        elif row.findAll('td')[8] == 'Hispanic':
            hispanic += 1

        if row.findAll('td')[9] in countyArg:
            countyArg[row.findAll('td')[9]] += 1

    return countyArg
    return black, white, hispanic

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counties(county)
    print scrape(url, county)
```

And running it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raceScraper.py", line 44, in <module>
    print scrape(url, county)
  File "raceScraper.py", line 29, in scrape
    if row.findAll('td')[8] == 'Black':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This error comes as a surprise to me, as the table does have 8 (actually 10) columns. Keep in mind I am using [this](https://www.tdcj.texas.gov/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html) table. All the answered on reading columns also use this list-like format, and since they were checked as answered, it's implied they were working, too. So any ideas? Is there an easier way I should do this that would still work? Or is there something fixable in my current code. Please keep in mind, I would like to keep this a HTML Web Scraper. It wont feel as accomplishing if I have to use a local CSV file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *skip the first header row* in the table.

Also, I would use a `table.os tr` [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

races = defaultdict(int)
counties = defaultdict(int)
for row in soup.select('table.os tr')[1:]:
    cells = row.find_all("td")

    race = cells[8].text
    races[race] += 1

    county = cells[9].text
    counties[county] += 1
```

Prints:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'Other': 2, u'Hispanic': 96, u'White': 233, u'White ': 1, u'Black': 195})
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'Lubbock ': 1, u'Bowie': 4, u'ValVerde': 1, u'El Paso ': 2, u'Smith': 9, u'Montgomery': 14, u'Coryell ': 1, u'Bailey': 1, u'Trinity': 1, u'Henderson': 2, u'Brown': 1, u'Sabine': 1, u'Shelby': 1, u'Victoria': 2, u'El Paso': 1, u'Harris': 123, u'Matagorda': 2, u'Parker ': 1, u'Scurry': 1, u'Navarro': 6, u'Tarrant': 38, u'San Jacinto': 1, u'Upshur': 1, u'Parker': 1, u'Jefferson ': 1, u'Anderson ': 1, u'Freestone': 1, u'Newton': 1, u'Potter': 10, u'Aransas': 1, u'Polk': 2, u'Smith ': 2, u'Pecos': 2, u'Caldwell': 1, u'Liberty': 2, u'Anderson': 3, u'Jefferson': 14, u'Nueces ': 3, u'Grayson': 3, u'Bowie ': 1, u'Nacogdoches': 1, u'Lamar': 2, u'Lee': 1, u'Milam': 1, u'Crockett': 1, u'Comal ': 1, u'Hamilton': 1, u'Randall': 2, u'Johnson': 2, u'Hopkins': 1, u'Kerr': 2, u'Clay': 1, u'Comal': 1, u'Kendall': 1, u'Taylor': 5, u'McLennan ': 1, u'Travis': 8, u'Refugio': 2, u'Cameron': 6, u'Nueces': 12, u'Wilbarger': 2, u'Hidalgo': 4, u'Gillespie': 1, u'Bexar': 42, u'Dallas': 52, u'Cherokee': 3, u'Collin': 6, u'Red River': 1, u'McLennan': 6, u'Tom Green': 3, u'Gregg': 5, u'San Patricio': 1, u'Montgomery ': 1, u'Red River ': 1, u'Bee': 1, u'Walker': 3, u'Dallas ': 2, u'Llano': 1, u'Bell': 3, u'Fort Bend ': 1, u'Brazoria': 4, u'Leon': 2, u'Kaufman': 1, u'Harrison': 1, u'Kerr ': 1, u'Denton': 6, u'Ellis': 2, u'Lubbock': 11, u'Randall ': 1, u'Wood': 1, u'Williamson': 3, u'Brazos': 11, u'Hale': 2, u'Jones': 1, u'Hardin': 1, u'Fort Bend': 4, u'Hunt': 3, u'Wichita': 2, u'Galveston ': 1, u'Morris': 1, u'Chambers': 1, u'Kleberg': 1, u'Bastrop': 1, u'Galveston': 5, u'Brazos ': 1, u'Atascosa': 1, u'Liberty ': 1, u'Harris ': 1, u'Dawson': 1})
```

Or, use a [`Counter` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Thanks! Works now. Just a quick question, how do I make sure it doesn't pick up the HTML tag? It's not counting counties/race because it's picking up the <td> tags. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Scoutdrago3 yes, this is because in your code, you are comparing the complete `td` element HTML presentation  `row.findAll('td')[8] == 'Black'`. But, instead, you need to use td's *text*: `row.findAll('td')[8].text == 'Black'`. Note that `defaultdict(int)` or a `Counter` is a more pythonic way to solve it.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll go ahead and use the default dict. Thanks. Sorry, one more question, when should I make a defaultdict and when should I make a regular dict?

Comment: Sorry, bare with me here. New problems are occurring. For some reason, there are sometimes 2 of the same counties written. Not sure why. Some have a 'u' before, others don't. I tried encoding the list into ascii, but there was still 2 copies, just no 'u'. EDIT: Just went through the site's HTML, for some reason, some counties have a space after them, other not. How can I make sure that it doesn't pick up spaces at the end? Keep in mind, some counties have spaces in the name, so I can't use `.replace`.